# How To Get A Value From Multiple Loops

Tags: php

My Problem To Solve

1. Get the schedule of a particular press based on range of dates.

I have the front end piece which accepts the press type and date ranges. When I click on search my logic presents me this

Date - 1

Schedule

Date - 2

Schedule

Now my programming logic is

1. Get all distict dates via this

`$getDatesSQL = "SELECT distinct date
                 FROM xxx.schedulemain 
                 where costcenter = '$costCenter' AND date between '$datef' AND '$datet' AND priority > '0' ";`

2. Iterate over each dates and get schedule

   ```
   for($i=0;$i<count($dates);$i++){
     $sqlGetCostCenters = "SELECT sm.notes,sm.priority,sm.id,jh.jobnumber,jh.customer,round(sum(sm.hours),1) as time,jh.description,jh.production,jh.division,jh.duedate,sm.componenetnumber,sm.date 
                         FROM xxx.jobheader as jh Left Join xxx.schedulemain as sm On jh.jobnumber = sm.jobnumber 
                         where sm.costcenter = '$costCenter' AND sm.date = '$dates[$i]' AND sm.priority > '0' 
                         Group By sm.costcenter,jh.jobnumber,jh.description,jh.production,jh.division,jh.duedate,sm.componenetnumber,sm.date,jh.customer,sm.id,sm.priority,sm.notes 
                         Order By sm.date ASC, sm.priority ASC";
   }
   ```

While iterating I also store total number of jobs for each particular date by doing the following

`$totalJobs[] = count($jobNumber);`

now when presenting the data I am facing an Issue.

Similar to fetching when presenting the data

1. I iterate over each dates

   ```
   for($i=0;$i<count($dates);$i++){
   //Now to get the data for that date I do inner iteration

         for($k=0;$k<$totalJobs[$i];$k++) {

         }
   }
   ```

So when the inner iteration starts, the first loop is fine but the second time the loop should start from all the jobs that have already looped through during first iteration.

I am not getting how to do that. Can some one please help?

Comment: It's difficult to make sense of the little bits of code you're giving, could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: I hope I understood your issue: You cannot iterate/fetch a SQL result-set multiple times / cannot rewind it. The solution to this often is to copy all the rows into an array (that you can foreach how often you want) once before your loop and work on that. [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/iterator-to-array) is really helpful for this.

Comment: @ParthKadakia, Please consider this as an example for optimizing your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask we can't understand your question and that makes helping you harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So sorry everyone if I confused with my question as it was a little harder to explain.

I have however found a solution. My solution was

1. Having a flag variable set to 0 on page load.
2. Setting loop $k = $flag variable
3. Once the iteration ends, update $flag with last run $k value.

This way when $k = $flag runs the second time it will start with value + 1 from previous iteration.

Once again sorry about the confusion.